# Different usage with "dinner"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is there a difference if we use the noun "dinner", the phrase "to have dinner" or the verb "to dinner"?:

1. Are you going for dinner with us?
2. Are you going to have dinner with us?
3. Are you going to dinner with us?

I'm not exactly sure though if in the last sentence the word "dinner" can be either a noun or a verb.

Which is more preferable and native way of saying it?

Comment: Dinner is the noun, the verb is dine.

Comment: @LucianSava Google, Merriam-Webster and Reverso.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I can understand it. It might help if you provide your research and what you think. Did the dictionary say that "dinner" could be a verb? Addressing your earlier comment, using Google Translate to analyze English words using the Russian translation is faulty and not advised.

Comment: Indeed, Google does all sorts of odd  things and should be avoided for these purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All 3 of your examples are using dinner as a noun... just in different ways.

The verb is dine.

> Are you going to dine with us? - verb
>   Are you going to have dinner with us? - noun

If you consider 'dinner' as a noun, then it has 2 potential meanings.
1. the name of the meal
2. the event at which that meal takes place.

This leads to your confusion over 1. & 3.

> Are you going to dinner with us?
>   Are you going for dinner with us?

both translate in effect as "Are you coming with us to the restaurant where we shall eat dinner?"

'for dinner' is slightly awkward in that particular sentence, but you could easily swap it to

> Shall we go to the restaurant for dinner?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Tetsujin's answer:

There's a word ["diner" (noun)](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=diner) meaning a 24/7 eating establishment (a public place to eat) formed by the suffix -er added to the verb *dine*.

By the way, of the four daily meals, the two that *can* be used as both a noun and a verb are [*lunch*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/lunch) and [*breakfast*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/breakfast).

Comment: **diner** is not really slang nowadays. It has made its way into the regular lexicon.